# How to parse decimal and hexadecimal string depending on number format to int

Tags: c#, parsing, hex

How do I parse a string with either a decimal number like 1234 or hexadecimal number prefixed with 0X1234 to an int in C#?

I have tried
`int.TryParse`and `Convert.ToInt32` But it seems like these function assumes that you know if you want to parse a decimal or  a hexidecimal value on prehand. I want to allow my user to input both formats.

Are there any standard functions that can decide by them selves if the input is formatted in hex or decimal format? Or do I have to write it myself?

Comment: You have to write the code like first check whether given string is decimal or hexa and then convert them into one type either in decimal and hexa and then conver to integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
int value = (int)new System.ComponentModel.Int32Converter().ConvertFromString(hexString);
```

where hexString can be 0x1234 and 1234. It handles hex and non hex cases.

Comment: Hex value must be prefixed by `0x` for this to work, otherwise exception will be thrown if string contains letters.

Comment: @Pavisa How do you parse 1234? Is it a hex or decimal? It does not make sense to parse without prefix marker.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about one unique method. But why not use conditional operator?

```
string input = "0xA3";
int result = input.Contains("0x") ? Convert.ToInt32(input , 16) : Convert.ToInt32(input);
```